# Apache https redirect URL error

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have an Apache website and I set up a redirect so that it will always go to the HTTPS version of the site. I added this under the port 80 Virtualhost configuration:

`Redirect permanent / https://example.com`

This works fine as I visit http://example.com, it is redirected to https://example.com.

But when I visit the site like http://example.com/page.php the trailing slash is removed. So instead of redirecting to https://example.com/page.php it is redirected to https://example.compage.php (which will result to an error).

I am using Ubuntu and the Apache version is: **Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)**

Comment: Have you thought about just using [htaccess](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/)?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest say to do this via Apache would be to enable `mod_rewrite`, then redirect the traffic with a `301` response.

In the Apache config file for the site, add this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If `mod_rewrite` is not enabled, you can do so like this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should give you what you need